# phonegap double redirect offline network connection

Tags: cordova, redirect, connection, offline

Trying to get a double redirect on phonegap when no connection or offline, but screen stays blank

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function onDeviceReady() {    
        InternetOK();    
    }
    function InternetOK() {    
        var networkState = navigator.connection.type;    
        if (networkState == Connection.NONE ){ 
            window.location = 'offline.html';    
        } else {
            window.location = 'app.html';
        }    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>            
</head>    
<body>            
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `cordova.js` after `<head>` tag

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```